# in a 'for' Loop show different total rows than query PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

this is my first question here, sorry for my bad english, the for loop result show "Done! 6000 rows affected." when the table have 6,235 rows, what is wrong?.

```
<?php
    //get the total rows of Members table.
        $count_members = mysqli_query($ipb_connection,'SELECT * FROM ' . $from_prefix. 'members');
        $totalMembers = mysqli_num_rows($count_members);

        mysqli_free_result($count_members);

        //start convertion
        $limit = 500;
        $output = '';
        //maybe there are better solutions for this
        for ($i=0;$i<=$totalMembers;$i+=$limit)
        {
            $get_members = mysqli_query($ipb_connection,'
                SELECT
                    m.member_id AS id_member, SUBSTRING(m.name, 1, 80) AS member_name,
                    m.joined AS date_registered, m.posts,
                    m.member_group_id AS id_group,
                    m.last_visit AS last_login, SUBSTRING(m.name, 1, 255) AS real_name,
                    IFNULL(m.msg_count_total, 0) AS instant_messages,
                    SUBSTRING(m.conv_password, 1, 64) AS passwd,
                    SUBSTRING(m.email, 1, 255) AS email_address,
                    STR_TO_DATE(IF (m.bday_year = 0 AND m.bday_month != 0 AND m.bday_day != 0, CONCAT("0004-", m.bday_month, '-', m.bday_day), CONCAT_WS('-', IF(m.bday_year <= 4, 1, m.bday_year), IF(m.bday_month = 0, 1, m.bday_month), IF(m.bday_day = 0, 1, m.bday_day))), "%Y-%m-%d") AS birthdate,
                    s.cache_content as signature,
                    "" AS lngfile, "" AS buddy_list,
                    "" AS pm_ignore_list, "" AS message_labels, "" AS personal_text,
                    "" AS time_format, "" AS usertitle, "" AS member_ip, "" AS secret_question,
                    "" AS secret_answer, "" AS validation_code, "" AS additional_groups,
                    "" AS smiley_set, "" AS password_salt,
                    pf.field_2 AS msn, pf.field_3 AS website_url, pf.field_6 AS location,
                    pf.field_1 AS aim, pf.field_4 AS icq, pf.field_8 AS yim,
                    IF(pf.field_5 = "m" AND pf.field_5 != "u",1,2) AS gender
                FROM {string:prefix}members m
                LEFT JOIN foro_content_cache_sigs s on m.member_id = s.cache_content_id
                LEFT JOIN foro_pfields_content pf on m.member_id = pf.member_id
                WHERE m.member_id != 0
                LIMIT ' . $i .', ' . $limit);

                $output = 'Done! ' . $i . ' rows affected.';
        }

        echo $output;
?>
```

the result must be "Done! 6235 rows affected!". is first time using for loops with limit querys.

regards.

EDIT:

i use the folowing way:

```
$limit = 100;
    $parts = $totalMembers / $limit;
    $output = '';
    $affected = 0;
    //maybe there are better solutions for this
    for ($i=0;$i<=$totalMembers;$i+=$limit * $parts)
    {
        //query here
    }
```

and now show me Done! 6235 rows affected, is correct that way?.

Comment: It could be that your `JOIN`, your `WHERE` or your `$limit` is... limiting the total amount of rows returned. If you use these conditions/filters and some of these don't match, you won't get the total amount of rows in that table. What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: Have you check your sql query to check it is ok ? If you do a count() (without loop, without limit), dit it return 6235 ?

Comment: this will always show you a multilple of limit and it will be the starting offset of the final run. if you changed limit to 100 you would see 6200 rows affected

Comment: @vonUbisch this code is only a test, actually what I try is to insert data every 500 rows.

Comment: @MaximePorté Yes the sql query is ok, without limit without loop returns 6235 rows

Comment: @Orangepill what is best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your new method is a lot worse. $parts = 63,25. In your case you will retrieve elements [0 to 100] and [6235]... It's not because the output display is okay the query too.
The first method was "not so bad", it done the job correctly, just the final display was wrong, and I gave you how to fix it.
With this new one, the final display is OK but the query don't do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a display problem, your query retrieve the 6235 rows because you display the "from limit" and not the "how many i retrieve"

If we do your loop step by step (we imagine it's until 1235, it's shorter)

```
$limit = 500;
$output = '';
//maybe there are better solutions for this
for ($i=0;$i<=$totalMembers;$i+=$limit)
{
   // query here
   $output = 'Done! ' . $i . ' rows affected.';
}
```

- **First loop:** $i = 0 to 500, ouput = "Done! 0 rows affected"
- **Second loop:** $i = 500 to 1000, ouput = "Done! 500 rows affected"
- **Thirt loop:** $i = 1000 to 1235, ouput = "Done! 1000 rows affected"

If your problem is "I don't retrieve all data", you don't have a problem

If your problem is the display, add to `$i` the count of rows from `mysqli_query` (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp)

So the result is `$ouput = "Done! ".($i + mysqli_num_rows($get_members))." row affected"`

Comment: Thanks Maxime Porté, i edit my question, i think found the solution.

Comment: Upvoted despite the fact that you are referencing [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) as apposed to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)